# Display linestring on Cartodb with SQL

Tags: carto, api, linestring

I have a Cartodb api for a separate map, I need to display a linestring for each time the sql is run, but not store the linestring in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Sure,

You can do it one of a few different ways.

First, run a SQL statement that combines all the rows into a line

```
SELECT ST_MakeLine(ST_Collect(the_geom_webmercator)) the_geom_webmercator FROM tablename
```

Second, do the same thing, but draw a line for each distinct group. You just need to tell the SQL statement what field to group them by

```
SELECT city_name, ST_MakeLine(ST_Collect(the_geom_webmercator)) the_geom_webmercator 
FROM tablename
GROUP BY city_name
```

Here, for each group of cities in your dataset, you would get a line for each distinct `city_name` value

Finally, you could use the `lag` function to draw a line between each row and the row previous in the dataset. See here http://blog.cartodb.com/maptime-entry/